# Dismissing sheet with button in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, dismiss, ios15

I am currently trying to figure out how to dismiss a sheet in SwiftUI.
I created a view for the Dismiss-Button because I want to use that button multiple times at different locations in the app. When the sheet pops up, pressing the button is not doing anything, I can only dismiss the sheet via swiping down on the screen.

I first tried to follow a YouTube tutorial, but it uses the deprecated .presentationMode
Therefore I am currently trying to make the .dismiss variable working, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
I already tried declaring .dismiss in the Button-View and Portfolio-View. I also used dismiss() and dismiss.callAsFunction().

Here is my Button-View (XMarkButton), the presented Sheet-View (PortfolioView) and my Home-View, where the sheet will be displayed:

**XMarkButton**

```
struct XMarkButton: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            dismiss.callAsFunction()
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "xmark")
                .font(.headline)
        })
    }
}
```

**PortfolioView**

```
struct PortfolioView: View {    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    Text("Portfolio")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Edit Portfolio")
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    XMarkButton()
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeView**

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var vm: HomeViewModel
    @State private var showPortfolio: Bool = false
    @State private var showPortfolioView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Background layer
            Color.theme.background
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .sheet(isPresented: $showPortfolioView) {
                    PortfolioView()
                        .environmentObject(vm)
                }
            
            VStack {
                homeHeader
                HomeStatsView(showPortfolio: $showPortfolio)
                
                SearchBarView(searchText: $vm.searchText)
                
                columnTitles
                
                if !showPortfolio {
                    allCoinsList
                    .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                }
                if showPortfolio {
                    portfolioCoinsList
                        .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                }
                
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I recommend going forward is to create a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Copying this code leads to a whole host of errors, as there are a handful of missing components.

Comment: ***Possible duplicate*** refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76111198/dismissing-sheet-with-button-in-swiftui/76112034?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C0.0000#76112034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get this up and running would be to move the `dismiss` functionality into the view that needs to be dismissed.

The problem with the current approach is you are attempting to dismiss the X button, not the actual view.

```
struct XMarkButton: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "xmark") //changed to image, can change color here if needed
            .font(.headline)
    }
}



struct PortfolioView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss // moved dismiss functionality here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    Text("Portfolio")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Edit Portfolio")
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    XMarkButton().onTapGesture { // on tap gesture calls dismissal
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

An alternate approach that keeps your same structure would be to use a completion handler - see below:

```
struct XMarkButton: View {
    var action: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            action()
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "xmark")
                .font(.headline)
        })
    }
}



struct PortfolioView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    Text("Portfolio")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Edit Portfolio")
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    XMarkButton {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```